# How to change enable/disable a <p:calendar> and an <p:inputTextarea> when a <p:selectBooleanCheckbox> is checked or not, using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this part of code:

```
<!-- /row -->
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="hcg-control-label span5">Ημερομηνία Ανάκλησης Ποινής</label>
                <div class="controls span7">
                    <p:calendar id="recallDate" styleClass="hcg-full-width cursor-pointer" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                value="#{penaltiesView.penalty.recallDate}" disabled="true"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar hcg-input-icon"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /span -->
    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="hcg-control-label span5">Σχόλια Ανάκλησης Ποινής</label>
                <div class="controls span7">
                    <p:inputTextarea rows="6" id="recallComments" styleClass="hcg-full-width" value="#{penaltiesView.penalty.recallComments}" disabled="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /span -->
    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="hcg-control-label span5">Ανάκληση - Ολοκλήρωση Πειθαρχικής Ποινής</label>
                <div class="controls span7">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="RevocationOrCompletion" styleClass="hcg-checkbox margin-bottom-10" value="#{penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}" disabled="#{!penaltiesView.canEdit()}" >
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="recallDate,recallComments"/>
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /span -->
    </div>
```

which produces the following components:
[image]

Now, what I want to do, is to make the calendar component and the Textarea to get enabled when I check the checkBox and if I uncheck it, they must be disabled again. The use of javascript due to requirements is not a valid way. I am having some difficulties on how to make this happen.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will need Javascript somehow... which is already used by the `p:calendar`.

Comment: Well, I found a way, but I have to change the "value" on all three components, which will disable the existing functionality. It's not possible to have two # inside a single value, right?

Comment: `disabled=#{penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}` in the input and calendar?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to have value="#{...} #{....}"?

Comment: I think only if you don't need to process that component, so if it's just for displaying purpose (else you will get a problem with reflection, it doesn't find the setter) AFAIK

Comment: Yeah, tried it myself and it doesn't seem to work that way, at least for my implementation. Do you have any idea on how to make it work though, without changing the current values? Could it be done only with JS?

Comment: Can you explain how the question about value is related to the above one? Isn't my first comment a solution for your case?

Comment: Oh god!! My bad... I deleted the ajax event earlier and when I tried your solution it didn't work. Sorry mate. It works like a charm!!

Comment: Thank you so much...The only thing that I changed was the ! `disabled=#{!penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements can't be updated because you have in your code disabled=true for calendar and textArea. If you want to change disable parameter depending on boolean checkbox than disabled value needs to be a value of boolean checkbox. Your boolean field also needs to have geters and setters.

```
<p:calendar id="recallDate" styleClass="hcg-full-width cursor-pointer" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            value="#{penaltiesView.penalty.recallDate}" disabled="#{penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}"/>
<p:inputTextarea rows="6" id="recallComments" styleClass="hcg-full-width" value="#{penaltiesView.penalty.recallComments}" disabled="#{penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}"/>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="RevocationOrCompletion" styleClass="hcg-checkbox margin-bottom-10" value="#{penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}" disabled="#{!penaltiesView.canEdit()}" >
                    <p:ajax update="recallDate recallComments" process="@this"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: Exactly mate. This is what fixed it. Again as i said in my comment on the question above, i just had to add a ! in `disabled=#{!penaltiesView.penalty.revocationOrCompletion}`